# Is Modern IE10/11 on Windows 8/8.1 using a multi-process architecture?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Desktop IE has been using a multi-process architecture since IE8 but what about Modern IE? Desktop IE's tabs show up under Background processes in Task Manager's Processes tab but Modern IE's tabs don't, although they are listed in the Details tab.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "Metro" IE also runs in separate processes:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what the Details tab of Task Manager shows. But it behaves differently in the Processes tab for some reason.

Comment: what do you mean with process tab?

Comment: The Processes tab of the Task Manager in Windows 8 and 8.1.

Comment: post a picture of what you see.

Comment: The multiple instances of the "iexplore" process arise from the fact that IE spins off multiple out-of-process COM servers to provide what appear to be a single instance's tabbed browsing windows. When looking at the command line for each iexplore instance, you can see things like SCODEF which are arguments for COM entry points.